# Substring extraction in TCL

Tags: string, substring, tcl

I'm trying to extract a sequence of characters from a string in TCL.
Say, I have `"blahABC:blahDEF:yadamsg=abcd"`. 
I want to extract the substring starting with `"msg="` until I reach the end of the string.
 
Or rather I am interested in extracting `"abcd"` from the above example string.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please take some time to read: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach: split the query parameter using `&` as the separator, find the element starting with "msg=" and then get the text after the `=`

```
% set string blahblah&msg=abcd&yada
blahblah&msg=abcd&yada
% lsearch -inline [split $string &] {msg=*}
msg=abcd
% string range [lsearch -inline [split $string &] {msg=*}] 4 end
abcd
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I just found out that the key=value pair I'm interested in is in fact the last parameter.
And apparently there are no delimiting characters at all. So it would be one big string like qwertyABC:aaaDEF:bbbmsg=asdf
So I should find "msg=" in this string and then read whatever follows until the end of the string.

Comment: No delimiters? Wow. You should fix that. If you're sure it's at the end, you can get the text following the last = with `set msg [lindex [split $params =] end]` or `set msg [regsub {.+=} $params ""]`

Comment: Yeah! :) I can't fix that because it is a HTTP POST response I am receiving. So I receive something like 
POST <URL> <version>
Host: <host>
Content-Type: <content_type>
Content-Length: <length>
message=<msg_I_care_about>

The regex works fine! Thanks again!

Comment: This assumes that the part you care about does **not** contain an `=`

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are the tools for these kind of tasks.
The general syntax in Tcl is:

```
regexp ?switches? exp string ?matchVar? ?subMatchVar subMatchVar ...?
```

A simple solution for your task  would be:

```
 set string blahblah&msg=abcd&yada

 # match pattern for a =, 0-n characters which are not an & and one &. The grouping with {} is necessary due to special  charactaer clash between  tcl and re_syntax

 set exp {=([^&]*)&}

 # -> is an idiom. In principle it is the variable containing the whole match, which is thrown away and only the submatch is used
b
 regexp $exp $string -> subMatch

 set $subMatch
```

A nice tool to experiment and play with regexps ist Visual Regexp (http://laurent.riesterer.free.fr/regexp/). I'd recommend to download it and start playing.

The relevant man pages are **re_syntax**, **regexp** and **regsub**

Joachim

Comment: Your regex can just be `{msg=([^&]*)}` -- without the trailing `&`, you can match even if the "msg" argument occurs at the *end* of the string. To avoid matching "othermsg=something", you can do `{(?:^|&)msg=([^&]*)}`

Answer (score 1):

Code

```
proc value_of {key matches} {

        set index [lsearch $matches "yadamsg"]

        if {$index != -1} {
                return [lindex $matches $index+1]
        }
        return ""
}

set x "blahABC:blahDEF:yadamsg=abcd:blahGHI"
set matches [regexp -all -inline {([a-zA-Z]+)=([^:]*)} $x]
puts [value_of "yadamsg" $matches]
```

Output:

```
abcd
```

**update**
upvar not needed. see comments.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `upvar` when you're not changing the value of the variable?

Comment: @PeterLewerin I was thinking to use the list reference instead of value.  Tcl probably optimizes to use reference until value is changed or used as a string etc. so I guess it's not necessary.

Comment: Well, Tcl does a few clever things in the runtime to pass things by reference and postpone copying of values until needed, but you're not gaining any advantage by passing a name and `upvar`ing that. It's actually a tiny bit more efficient to pass the list as a value, since the `upvar` isn't without cost.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `string first`.
Using that, you can retrieve the index of the first occurrence of the searched string.

```
% set s blahABC:blahDEF:yadamsg=abcd
% string first "msg=" $s
20
```

Then you can filter out the rest of the string using `string range` that extracts the portion of the string, given start/end index (or `end` if you are interested in extracting from given index to the end)

```
% string range $s [string first "msg=" $s] end
msg=abcd
```

If you want to get only 'abcd', then just add 4 to the start index (to exclude, basically, 'msg=' characters)

```
% string range $s [string first "msg=" $s]+4 end
abcd
```